# How to install an Insteon switch on a multi-way circuit

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am attempting to install either an Insteon ToggleLinc Switch (#2466SW) or a Insteon Micro On/Off (2443-222) to control two ceiling fans with lights. The builder/previous owner created a multi-way circuit with 6 wall switches to control the fans. Both fans are controlled at the same time by the switches. I hired an electrician and he was not able to figure out how to get one of the Insteon devices wired in to replace one of the wall switches.

From what I have read using the ToggleLinc switch in a multi-way circuit requires that all of the existing switches be replaced with Insteon ToggleLinc switches. Can anyone verify that?

If that’s correct, is it possible to replace one of the 6 switches with the Insteon Micro On/Off switch?

Attached are 3 photos of the wiring to the existing switch that I want to replace. If I can use the Micro On/Off switch, does it matter which of the six switches I attach it to? A friend told me that it might make a difference I were to connecting to the first or last switch in the circuit.

Thanks in advance. 
[switch1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq1Mk.jpg)
[image: switch2]
[image: box]

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the other switch boxes in this circuit?

Comment: Also, do the fan and the light share a switch, or are they on separate switches?

Comment: You're going to lose your mind really quickly if you don't mark those wires. I strongly suggest get a 5-pack of colored electrical tape and wrap all the messengers with yellow wire (messengers are on the brass screws on a 3-way).  Since both messengers are interchangeable and do the same thing, mark them both yellow.  If you have 2 separate 3-ways too near each other, or want to distinguish the wires in a 4-way, my alternate messenger color is blue.  (or whatever's in your kit, save red for switched-hot).

Comment: @Harper in the case of insteon, what was a traveler or "messenger" isn't going to be anymore, and in 99.9% of the cases they are going to be re-purposed as constant hot and neutral, to feed a "device", that device may or may not actually switch a load (cap the red wire on the switch if it doesn't)... Then multiway switching is "created" by the magic of grouping by linking and "scenes".  There are no special "slave" switch devices requiring special wiring.

Comment: If Insteon makes you bus everything as always-hot, neutral and signal, that's great.   I would still tag them in case he ever decides to rollback to mechanical 3-ways, or if he's only doing exploratories.

Answer (score 1):

Insteon is very simple to install.

The concept of 3-way, 4-way, or multi switch circuits doesn’t exist in the traditional “wired” sense.

Use the 2466 in the last switch position before the load.  The red wire from the switch goes to the load.

Now you can use additional 2466’s (or many other insteon devices) at the other locations.  Basically the 2466 needs hot, neutral and ground.   In these other locations you cap the red wire on the switch because the switch isn’t actually switching a load.  Don’t have a hot and neutral at the switch location?  You re-wire the circuit to make it happen for your case.  You had 2 travelers before, you re-wire the circuit to make those old travelers hots and neutrals.

Now to get your multiway switching to work you utilize the insteon linking process.  This is best done thru your hub, but there is also a painstaking manual linking process described in insteon manuals.  Hint: if done thru a hub: for straight multi-way switching add each device individually to the hub, then create a scene and add all the devices as a “controller”.  (A controller is also a responder, and in a standard multi-way switching scene every device should be a “controller” and no device should be classified as “responder”)

(Disclaimer: the only two non-insteon switches in my house are both garbage disposal switches.  I've encountered every wiring possibility at some point. If you need more info ask away and I'll edit)